# MKStoreKit restore purchases always success

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I'm trying to make a simple IAP for delete all the Ad of my app.
When I buy IAP it work, but when I try to `restore` purchase with clear sandbox account (which have never buy the IAP), it work.

So, the `restorePurchases()` always work, even if the user don't have buy the IAP previously.

There is my code : 
When user select restore button I perform this method :

```
func restaureIAP() {
    PKNotification.toast("Chargement en cours...")
    MKStoreKit.sharedKit().restorePurchases()
}
```

I have also add observer :

```
// Product restaure
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitRestoredPurchasesNotification,
            object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (note) -> Void in
                PKNotification.success("Restauré !")
                print ("Succes restaure: \(note.object)")

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isPurchase")
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitRestoringPurchasesFailedNotification,
            object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (note) -> Void in
                PKNotification.failed("Erreur")
                print ("Failed restaure: \(note.object)")
        }
```

This app is available on the `AppStore`, and have the same problem : buy IAP work but `restore` purchase are always successful.

Have you any ideas ?

Comment: What is type of your IAP product ?

Comment: what is value of the `transactionState` property?

Comment: It's Non consumable IPA

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem with an auto-renewing subscription product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check Restored Transactions with `MKStoreKitRestoredPurchasesNotification` and `kMKStoreKitRestoringPurchasesFailedNotification` observers.

```
 MKStoreKit.sharedKit().startProductRequest()
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitRestoredPurchasesNotification,
  object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (note) -> Void in
    print ("Restored product: \(note.object)")
}

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitRestoringPurchasesFailedNotification,
  object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (note) -> Void in
    print ("Restored failed")
}
```

Comment: It was the wrong code, I change it on my first post. It don't work with MKStoreKitRestoredPurchasesNotification and kMKStoreKitRestoringPurchasesFailedNotification